# Convert thymeleaf to freemarker

Tags: thymeleaf, freemarker

Please help, i cann't find in **freemarker** guide how to convert from **thymeleaf** this:
[lists.isEmpty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2Lzq.jpg) and [for each](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIjIZ.jpg)

```html
 <th:block th:if="${#lists.isEmpty(employees)}">
        <h3>No employee</h3>
    </th:block>
    <th:block th:unless="${#lists.isEmpty(employees)}">
```

```html
 <tr th:each="contact,iterStat : ${employees}">
                    <td th:text="${iterStat.count}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${contact.name}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${contact.phone}"></td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's hardly a guide specifically for that... but if you look at `#list`, `#if` and `${...}` in the FreeMarker Manual, surely you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Something like this? (sketch, not tested)

```
<#list employees as contact>
 <tr>
    <td>${contact?index}
    <td>${contat.name}</td>
    <td>${contact.phone}</td>
 </tr>
<#else>
 <h3>No employee</h3>
</#list>
```

**Notes**

- `<#list>` Will generate a `<tr>` element  for each item in the employees sequence, containing `<td>`'s for each field.
- If the employees sequence is empty it will generate the `<h3>` element.
  See [List Directive Doc](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html)
- It gets the zero based index of the item using the build-in function 
  `?index`. See built-ins and loop variables in the help. [Freemarker built-ins Doc](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html#ref_builtin_index). If you want one based, you can add one to it.

Answer (score 0):

***It's works***

```
<#list employees as contact>
 <tr>
    <td>${contact?index}
    <td>${contat.name}</td>
    <td>${contact.phone}</td>
 </tr>
<#else>
 <h3>No employee</h3>
</#list>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks